# Installation V8.js in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: v8, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install V8 according to this instruction http://www.php-js.com/documentation/v8

1. git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
2. export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
3. gclient
4. fetch v8

And I get this error while running `fetch v8`:

> Error: Command 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume
>   --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format.sha1' returned non-zero exit status
>   1
>
> Failed to fetch file
>   gs://chromium-clang-format/942fc8b1789144b8071d3fc03ff0fcbe1cf81ac8
>   for v8/buildtools/linux64/clang-format. [Err: panic: failed to execve
>   "/home/erniesto77/.vpython-root/e63758/bin/python": cannot allocate
>   memory

What could possibly be causing this? And whether it is possible to install V8 on WSL in General?

Answer (score 0):

I run `gclient --help` and it gives me warning that **gclient not yet support python3**, [image]I fix it by change my python command pointing to my python2.

calling `fetch v8` works fine then.